# fetch records between 'current date ' and next 5 days(future date) in oracle

Tags: sql, string, oracle, datetime, where-clause

```
Select * from dual where between  to_date(date,'YYYY-MM-DD') = '2020-10-01'
                    and to_date(date,'YYYY-MM-DD') + 5
```

*this is correct way to write query?*

1.format of date is varchar2
2.required data between current date and next 5 days
3.first needs to convert into date format.
4. next 5 should be +5 in current day

Comment: where _something_ between...

Comment: Don't store dates in a varchar2 column, use proper date data type!

Comment: column name is 'date',

Comment: Hi Jarlh, column is already pre defined, we need to convert this,
but when i am using (to_date and to_char ) i am getting error :oracle full year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0

Comment: Then you have data issues thanks to your badly typed date. If you are using Oracle 12.2+ then you can work around your strings that are supposed to represent dates but don’t with the on conversion error clause https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/TO_DATE.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably meant to write:

```
where to_date(mydate, 'yyyy-mm-dd') between trunc(sysdate) 
                                      and trunc(sysdate) + 5
```

Rationale:

- `date` is a reserved word; I assume that's not the actual name of your column, so I used something else; if that's the real name, then you need to surround it with double quotes (`"date"`, or `"DATE"`, or else, depending on how it was initially defined)
- `mydate` is a string so you need to turn it to a date: for this, you can use `to_date()`
- you then compare it to the current date, without the time portion : `trunc(sysdate)`, and the same date 5 days later

Note, however, that this would be more efficiently expressed as follows:

```
where mydate between to_char(trunc(sysdate), 'yyyy-mm-dd') 
               and to_char(trunc(sysdate + 5), 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

This avoids the date conversion on the string column, and instead converts the interval bounds. Here, string comparison is possible, because the format of the string you are storing allows it (it it was stored as `dd-mm-yyyy'` for example, this would not be possible).

Let me, however, strongly suggest to store your dates as `date`s rather than string. You should always use the proper datatype, for many reason, such as data integrity and efficency.

Comment: Isn't DATE a reserved word in Oracle? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words

Comment: @jarlh: yes. I doubt that's the actual name of OP's column, but I added a bullet point to mention that.

Comment: i am gettting error
ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0

Comment: @TulsiThakur: then you have invalid dates in your column. If you use the second suggestion in the answer, you will not get that error (*but* you might get dates that are out of the range though...).

Comment: "i am gettting error ORA-01841"  That is because your "date" column is incorrectly typed and has invalid data in it.  When you use a character type data column to store dates, there is nothing to prevent one date being '2010-10-28' and the next being '05-04-12', and the next being "here's yer sign".  You've just proven why it is so important to use properly typed data columns. In the case dates, that means the column needs to be typed as DATE.